# How to know if a video file length is the same as its original lenght

Tags: android

I am downloading video files using retrofit streaming method and saving them inside external storage. I wish to delete any file that does not reach 100% download ( i.e if 10MG is successfully downloaded out of a 20MB video file), the file is saved as though it is 100% complete, but when playing, let's say the video length is 30seconds, when it reaches 15 seconds, it displays 'bad file, can't play'. My wish is to know whether or not the file is complete or not by locating file path with the example code below;

```
File f = new File(path);
boolean d = f.delete();
if (f.exist()){
    // check if file will not display 'bad file' while playing.
    // if file will break while playing, then execute f.delete() to delete file so a new one can be downloaded
}
```

Comment: Does the video service provide a hash value, such as SHA256 or MD5, that you can use to verify your download?

Comment: The video is an mp4 file

Comment: Can you hash the mp4 and provide that hash with the download or some other way? If so, then verifying that the download is not corrupt in anyway is pretty simple.

Comment: No the service doesn't provide such information, all I have is the URL string which I used in Retrofit to download the video